# Negate this regex /(\n.)/g

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript `/(\n.)/g` captures a line-feed and the first character that follows it.
I need the inverse of it. That is anything but a line-feed and the first character that follows it.

I tried `/(?!\n.)/g` but it is not working.

eg

```
const regex = /\n./g;
const str = `All the world's a stage,
And all the men and women merely players;
They have their exits and their entrances,`;
const subst = ` `;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

this will return :

> Substitution result:  All the world's a stage, nd all the men and
>   women merely players; hey have their exits and their entrances,

however i want:

> Substitution result:  A T

replace everything except a line-feed and the first character that follows it

Comment: Any example string and expected result? Are you trying to remove text or extract it? Maybe you just want to use `s.split(/\n./)`?

Comment: Using negated character class (set): `/[^\n]./g`

Comment: JavaScript regexes don't support lookbehind unfortunately, but @falsetru's comment should work

Comment: Acc. to what you ask, your final results should be `"\nA\nT"`. See Maciek's answer below. Else, you need to use a matching regex like `/\n(.)/g` and join the values inside Group 1. See [**this demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/hLvbogLc/).

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/hLvbogLc/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its true, just feared "\nA\nT" might confuse someone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you want to do is not negation but you can try this;

```js
const data = `All the world's a stage,
And all the men and women merely players;
They have their exits and their entrances,`

const func = data => data.replace(/.*((?:\r?\n|\r).).*/g, '$1')

console.log(func(data))
```

Comment: Note that in case a string contains CR symbols, this solution won't work well because `.` does not match carriage returns in JS regex. Also, since `.` does not match LF, the `*?` should be replaced with `*` to work quicker.